# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

please help me solve this problem when I run this code, an error count () occurs: The parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable when I want to get no_st

```
public function get_no_st(Request $request){

        $no_org = null;
        $tgl    = $request->tgl ?: date('Y-m-d');
        $tgl    = Helper::saveDateIndo( $tgl );
        $max_no_st = $request->max_no_st ?: null;

        if ( $request->org == 'KPA'){
            $no_org = 'KPA.MBU';
        }else if ( $request->an ) {
            $no_org = $this->organisasi->select('kode_surat_atas_nama', 'kode_surat')->where('id', $request->org)->first();
            $no_org = ( count($no_org) > 0
                        ? ( trim($no_org->kode_surat_atas_nama) != null ? $no_org->kode_surat_atas_nama : $no_org->kode_surat )
                        : @$no_org->kode_surat );
        } else {
            $no_org = $this->organisasi->select('kode_surat')->where('id', $request->org)->first();
            $no_org = (count($no_org) > 0 ? $no_org->kode_surat : null);
        }

        if(!$max_no_st) {
            $max_no_st = $this->model->select('no_st_increment');
            if ( $request->org == 'KPA') {
                $max_no_st = $max_no_st->where('is_kpa', true);
            } else {
                $max_no_st = $max_no_st->where('pt_organisasi_id', $request->org);
            }
            if ( $tgl )
            {
                $max_no_st  = $max_no_st->where(DB::raw('EXTRACT( YEAR FROM tgl_awal )'), date('Y', strtotime($tgl)) );
            }
            $max_no_st  = $max_no_st->max('no_st_increment') + 1;
        }

        $no_st      = 'ST-'.$max_no_st.'/'.($no_org ?: '-').'/'.date('n/Y', strtotime( $tgl ));

        return $no_st;
    }
```

Comment: `$no_org` is not a collection or array. It's a single object. You can't count a single object. 

From the looks of your code, I'm guessing you're trying to check whether or not `$this->organisasi->select('kode_surat_atas_nama', 'kode_surat')->where('id', $request->org)->first();` returns a result.

Comment: I am stacking on it please help me out if you solved this issue

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to count an object type data, but you will only be able to count an array.
If you still want to count the properties of an object you can simply cast that object to an array.
Like this:

```
count((array) $no_org);
```

This will return the total number of properties of $no_org;

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the PHP version and Laravel version you are using.

Read [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables)

You can turn your result into array.

```
$no_org = ( count((array)$no_org)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are  `count()` something that cannot implements Countable.

`->first()` will return an object that cannot implements countable.

`->get()` will return an collection that can be countable.

However you just need to find the one object of `organisasi` , so
you can just use `empty()`
like :

```php
empty($no_org)
```

Comment: you can also use `is_object($no_org)`